# Getting the result suggestion list in jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

I'm using the [jquery autocomplete plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete) and I am comming up to a few problems:
I have a lot of data and when I type data a long suggestion list is shown and a scrollbar is needed:

```
$("#txtName").autocomplete(data,
                                  { matchContains: true,
                                      minChars: 0,
                                      max: 3000,
                                      scroll: true,
                                      //scrollHeight: 180,
                                      width: 200
                                  });
```

but, the scrollbar does't work properly in IE (it's a known issue, I searched alot but have'nt found a relevant solution).

so I decided to block the suggestion list popup and get the suggestion list results into an array or somthing similar and show them in my control.
my problem is - How do I get that list?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you not using the autocomplete provided by JQueryUI library ? It provides event handling to accomplish what you want.

Comment: you mean this - http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#default ?
I thought they are all the same (I'm new in jQuery.)
From where can I download the stylesheet and the code?

Comment: are you talking about appendTo? If you are, it does'nt work for me. I can't find a way to format the resault.
btw, is there a way to add a scroll bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer (part of it, I still need to work on it).
I'll first post the code and then explain it:

```
$(function ()
{
    var names = [
        { label: 'Java', value: '1' },
        { label: 'C++', value: '2' },
        { label: 'C#', value: '3' },
        { label: 'Jquery', value: '4' },
        { label: 'Javascript', value: '5' },
        { label: 'ASP', value: '6' },
        { label: 'Pearl', value: '7' },
        { label: 'VB', value: '8' },
        { label: 'Ajax', value: '9' },
        { label: 'Json', value: '10' }];

    $("#txtName").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: names,
        delay: 500
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function (ul, item)
    {
        //add data to my control, need to take care of earasing each time.
        var elOptNew = document.createElement('option');
        elOptNew.text = item.label;
        elOptNew.value = item.value;
        lst.add(elOptNew);

        //this code here adds the items to the popup thats built in.(it's written in jquery-ui.min.js)
        return $("<li></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
```

Html:

```
    <input id="txtName"/> 
    <select id="lst" size='10'></select>
```

The added part (`_renderItem`) adds one item each time, so you can do whatever you want to do with an item. I decided to add it to a list.

The other thing that's not done is erasing the list each time. I still need to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Quickly looking through that Plugin's API, I don't see any events that let you handle the response from a server call-back. You may want to switch and use the [official JQuery UI library](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) for your auto-completing needs. There is an `appendTo` option that might suit your need.

Comment: I can't find from where to download the script, I tried ftom here: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js but the autocomplete does'nt work properly.

Comment: What aspect of it isn't working? That is the one that is being used on thousands of web sites across the Internet. Usually when I use it and it doesnt seem to be working, I usually just have it configured incorrectly.

Comment: I Downloaded this: http://jqueryui.com/download - the whole package. My html looks like this: <input id="txtName"/> <select size='50' id="lst"></select> And this is my code: names in an array with data. $("#txtName").autocomplete({source: names, appendTo: "#lst" });

Comment: what i'm trying to do, is when entering a text to txtName, the suggesion list will be shown in lst, but nothing happens!! if I remove the row appendTo: "#lst", it works like a regular autocomplete but with no scrollbar an I have a very long list!!